# skipping empty facets in seaborn facetgrid for annotations

Tags: python, plot, facet, seaborn

I'm working on putting together a [Seaborn facetgrid](http://web.stanford.edu/%7Emwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html) with data that leaves some grids empty.  Furthermore, I'm annotating each facet with some statistics, however I'm not sure how to "skip" the empty facets so that the annotations fall on the proper facet.

`g.axes.flat` is of length 9 (9 facets have data); however when I place an annotation on each element in `g.axes.flat`, it isn't being placed where I expect.

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(mapping, col=options.facetCol, row=options.facetRow, col_order=sorted(cols), hue=options.group, sharex=False)
g = g.map(sns.distplot, options.axis)

# label each facet with stats
grouped = mapping.groupby([options.facetRow, options.facetCol])
for ax, (name, df) in zip(g.axes.flat, grouped):
    df2 = df.groupby(options.group) # group by each thing that has its own color and run stats on it

    for i, (group, data) in enumerate(df2):
        x = data[options.axis]

        # calculate stats and create label
        n = len(x)
        mean = np.mean(x)
        std = np.std(x)
        label = r"%s: n=%s, $\mu$=%.2f $\sigma$=%.2f" %(group, n, mean, std)
        ax.annotate(label, xy=(0.05,0.9-(i*0.05)), xycoords='axes fraction', ha='left', size=8)
```

[image]

## EDIT

I've created an annotation function and I'm passing it to the `map()` [as recommended]; however I'm uncertain how to pass label names to the function and how to get the annotations (there are two for each facet) to shift in the y direction.  Any more suggestions?

```
g = g.map(stats, options.axis)

def stats(x, **kwargs):
    ax = sns.distplot(x, **kwargs)

    # calculate stats and create label
    n = len(x)
    mean = np.mean(x)
    std = np.std(x)
    label = r"%s: n=%s, $\mu$=%.2f $\sigma$=%.2f" %('moo', n, mean, std) # temporary label, need to pass it through function
    i = 1 # temporary, needs to increment to shift annotations so they aren't on top of each other

    # create annotation
    ax.annotate(label, xy=(0.05,0.9-(i*0.05)), xycoords='axes fraction', ha='left', size=8)
```

[image]

Comment: This is more of a pandas question than a seaborn one; you need to iterate over all groups and not just the ones that have data. But the best thing to do would be to define a function that does the annotation and then pass it to `g.map`.

Comment: To shift the annotation, a bit of a hack, but I'd do something like `y = .7 if ax.texts else .8`. I'm not sure what you mean by "pass label names to the function", but `map` will pass the name of the hue level to the `label` parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The final solution was:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(mapping, col=options.facetCol, row=options.facetRow, col_order=sorted(cols), hue=options.group, sharex=False)
g.map(sns.distplot, options.axis)
g.map(stats, options.axis)

# custom function that allows us to create a distplot and add offset annotations to each facet that is not empty
def stats(x, label, **kwargs):

    # get a reference to the currently active axes
    ax = plt.gca()    

    # calculate stats and create label
    n = len(x)
    mean = np.mean(x)
    std = np.std(x)
    label = r"%s: n=%s, $\mu$=%.2f $\sigma$=%.2f" %(label, n, mean, std)

    # create annotation
    y = 0.9 - len(ax.texts) * 0.05
    ax.annotate(label, xy=(0.05,y), xycoords='axes fraction', ha='left', size=8)
```

Comment: I edited the code to take the `distplot` call out of `stats` and pass it directly to `map`, which makes the annotation code more general.

Comment: Where does 'ax' come from in this context? I guess it must be an Axes object, but how do you get it? Thanks!

Comment: I'll let @mwaskom chime in since I'm not sure; in the meantime, the original answer is found here: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/382818e2-a6e4-4136-9eda-dbae5195ee10/view-source